# why #{params.property} cannot get value in mybatis?

Tags: mybatis

My daoService is

```
int insertSelective(@Param("series") Series series, @Param("table") Map<String, String> table);
```

My mapper.xml is

```
<insert id="insertSelective" statementType="STATEMENT">
insert into ${table.seriesTable}
<trim prefix="(" suffix=")" suffixOverrides="," >
  <if test="series.seriesName != null" >
    series_name,
  </if>
<trim prefix="values (" suffix=")" suffixOverrides="," >
  <if test="series.seriesName != null" >
    '${series.seriesName}',
  </if>
</trim>
```

When I user '${series.seriesName}', I can get the value,
but #{series.seriesName} cannot. Why?

Comment: What error do you get when you use `#{series.seriesName}`?

Comment: I have resolved it，it's because # is used in preparedstatement. Just need remove `statementType="STATEMENT"`.